# PostgreSQL - ALTER SEQUENCE query never completes

Tags: postgresql

I'm using Postgres for the first time and have been experimenting a bit. I have a table that I created with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id SERIAL,
name int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

and I'm trying to reset the sequence for the `id` column with this query (after emptying the table of all current data):

```
ALTER SEQUENCE test_id_seq RESTART WITH 1;
```

But when I run this query it runs indefinitely. All previous queries I've run complete within milliseconds but this has run for upwards of 3 minutes before I kill it. What should I be doing differently

Comment: Are you on version 10.1? There is apparently a bug with sequence resets being incredibly slow as a result of making sequence updates transactional https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Slow-alter-sequence-with-PG10-1-td6002088.html

Comment: I am using version 10.5, I will look into the solutions in that link to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: After reading through that thread I'm not entirely clear on how I should change my query to work around the issue. I don't have a very in depth knowledge of SQL, mainly just setting up and managing tables. Could I get some guidance on how to modify the query in my original post?

Comment: Maybe it's waiting for a lock. Did you check `pg_stat_activity` (from a different session)

Comment: I don't think it's a lock as I'm still able to run other queries without any delays, it seems to be just this particular command that has issues.

Comment: A  lock won't necessary block other queries, but  it might block DDL statements. So **did** you check `pg_stat_activity`?

Comment: If it is a result of the update, you should be able to run your original query and have it finish...eventually. This is fine if you just need to reset the sequence this one time. Just be patient and let it finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely caused by a lock.

See if there are sessions with status “idle in transacion” in `pg_stat_activity`.

Check for locks using

```
SELECT pid, mode FROM pg_locks WHERE relation = 'test_id_seq'::regclass;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug with Postgres https://www.postgresql-archive.org/Slow-alter-sequence-with-PG10-1-td6002088.html

You could try a hacky reset, such as incrementing the sequence by a negative amount to get what you want:
`SELECT * FROM <sequence_name>;`

look at the column "last_value" to determine how much to subtract from the current value. Lets say your sequence's last_value is 1000:
`ALTER SEQUENCE <sequence_name> INCREMENT BY -999;`

Execute the subtraction
`SELECT NEXTVAL('< sequence_name>');`
This should reset the sequence back to one

Reset the sequence to its original increment value:
`ALTER SEQUENCE <sequence_name_> INCREMENT BY 1`

I'm not on this version of postgres, so I can't test it for you...but it's worth a shot.